# Allow user to add HTML in textarea without using 3rd party plugins

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, textarea

I want to allow user to add html in textarea like iframe or script on my backend  but it is not working with codeigniter. I testes is working fine on normal PHP and getting html code in post data.

But for some reason it is not working in codeigniter and post data returns false.
I did tried with `$this->input->post` and `$_POST` both are returning false. Also `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;` is set to false tried setting this to `TRUE` as well no result.

Also i tried to post data with ajax as well but still same result.

Comment: Show how you are submitting the form data. You also can view the form data being submitted in the developer console under the request, view `form data`.

Comment: @user3783243 here it is  http://prntscr.com/s2l7od It will be array of fields.

Comment: So that is showing the data is submitting.  It is an array but should be there. Are you accessing as `$_POST['code']` or `$_POST['code'][0]`?

Comment: Even if i am accessing it via `$_POST['code']` it should show array of fields, it all empty and returning false. Even checked with `$_POST` only.

Comment: what plugin you use sir?

Comment: @GilangPratama i am not using any plugin for this.